# How to use Html.EditorFor for a model property so that it clears out the existing value and takes the new value entered by the user in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, editorfor

I have a property that is defined in my model as below:

```
    public decimal? Amount { get; set; }
```

I have a column in my table named as 'Amount' and it can have values for Amount column.

Then I have a view, where I need to have an editor for Amount column. I have it defined as below:

```
 @Html.Editor("Amount", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

My issue is, I want the Editor area, to be empty when the view is rendered, but it is taking the value from database and assigning it in my editor field.

I want user to be able to enter data (Amount) value in the editor field, and then, on my submit button click, I want to pass the new entered data to my controller and override the Amount column in database with the new value entered by user.

My button, is defined as below:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Submit", "EnterAmount", new { id = Model.ItemID, amount = Model.Amount }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
```

When I run my code setup, my editor field is not empty, and it's pre filled with the data that is already in the database. I do not need this. I want my editor field to be empty.

2nd - if i clear out the pre filled amount, and enter a new amount, and then n I click my submit button, it's not taking the newly entered data and instead using the same previous data.

How can I get this working?

Thanks!

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink()` is razor code and is evaluated on the server before its sent to the view. `new { id = Model.ItemID, amount = Model.Amount }` will set the route/query string values based on the original values of the model, not what you have edited. You need a form and post the form to a method marked with `[HttpPost]`. (a link is for getting data and should not be used to call a method that changes data)

Answer (score 0):

You have to  use:

```
@Html.Editor
```

For example:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

[ASP.NET Razor - C# and VB Code Syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/razor_syntax.asp)